# WebGL Drawing Multiple Shapes of Different Colour

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, fragment-shader

I am currently in the process of learning both WebGL and Javascript. An assignment is requiring me to create multiple shapes using WebGL and for them to all be different colours, however, I am unable to figure out how to set it so that each shape has it's own colour.

```js
// HelloTriangle.js (c) 2012 matsuda
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '}\n';
 
// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'precision mediump float;\n' +
  'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
  '}\n';
 
function main() {
  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
 
  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }
 
  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }
 
  // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if (n < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }
 
  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
 
  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 
  // Draw the rectangle
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Triangle One
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, 3); // Triangle Two
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 6, 6); // Triangle Fan
}
 
function randColor() // Assign Random color values
{
    setR = Math.random();
    setG = Math.random();
    setB = Math.random();
}
 
function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    0.1,   0.1,   -0.1,  -0.1,   0.1,  -0.1,  // First Triangle
    0.15,  0.25,   0.1,   0.2,  -0.1,   0.2,  // Second Triangle
    0.75,  0.65,   0.35,  0.25,  0.65,  0.55,
    0.65,  0.25,   0.35,  0.45,  0.25,  0.15  // Triangle Fan
  ]);
  var n = 6; // The number of vertices
 
  // Create a buffer object
  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }
 
  // Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  // Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }
 
  // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
  var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
  if (!u_FragColor) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
    return;
  }
 
  //Pass color of point to u_FragColor
  randColor();
  gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, setR, setG, setB, 1.0);
 
  // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 
  // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
 
  return n;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl" width="400" height="400">
  Please use a browser that supports "canvas"
</canvas>

<script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/cuon-utils.js"></script>
```

I am pretty sure the code that I am supposed to modify is the following:

```
//Pass color of point to u_FragColor
randColor();
gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, setR, setG, setB, 1.0);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make it so that it stores a value for each shape I am attempting to draw. I thought that by making it randomly change the colours before drawing each time, that would solve it, but that wasn't the case. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [The last example on this page draws rectangles in random colors](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thank you for this, however, I am having difficulty determining which part makes it so that each drawn object is a different colour, which was my problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out!

Thank you, this did help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

What did you try? There's a lot of issues with that code and it gets errors trying to run it.

First off `initShaders` returns the shader on `gl.program` which makes zero sense. WebGL applications usually have multiple shader programs. Instead you want `initShaders` to return a program so you can do things like

```
var program1 = initShaders(gl, vertex1ShaderSource, fragment1ShaderSource);
var program2 = initShaders(gl, vertex2ShaderSource, fragment2ShaderSource);
var program3 = initShaders(gl, vertex3ShaderSource, fragment3ShaderSource);
..etc...
```

Next up `initVertexBuffers` references a variable called `program` but no such variable exists.

`initVertexBuffers` is setting uniforms but you want to set uniforms just before you start drawing, not when initializing vertices.

`initVertexBuffers` is also looking up attribute and uniform locations and checking for errors. On the one hand it's not bad to check for those kinds of errors per se but it makes your code harder to debug in other ways. In most WebGL programs, if you get no errors but something doesn't appear on the screen the first thing to do is make your fragment shader return a solid color

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_FragColor;
void main() {
  //gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); // return red
}
```

When you do that WebGL will optimize out the unsued `u_FragColor` and your code that's checking that you got the location for `u_FragColor` will fail making it impossible to debug your shaders.

I'd suggest [reading some other tutorials on WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org).

To draw multiple copies of the same shape the process is generally

At init time

```
 set up program
 look up attribute locations and uniform locations
 setup vertices for shape
```

At draw time

```
 setup attributes for shape
 gl.useProgram(program for shape)
 for each instance of shape
   set uniforms
     set a matrix uniform to position and orient the shape
     set a color uniform for the color
   drawArrays/drawElements
```

To draw multiple different shapes the process is usually

At init time

```
 set up programs
 look up attribute locations and uniform locations
 for each shape
   setup vertices for shape
```

At draw time

```
 for each shape
   gl.useProgram(program for shape) (if different from last shape)
   setup attributes for shape (if different from last shape)
   set uniforms
     set a matrix uniform to position and orient the shape
     set a color uniform for the color
   drawArrays/drawElements
```

As for matrices for positioning and orienting shapes [see this article](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html)